# JavaScript - Diferença entre img.src="path" e img.setAttribute('src','path')

Tags: javascript

Qual a diferença entre configurar o caminho de uma imagem em JavaScript usando por exemplo uma variável :

```
img.src="caminho"
```

E setando o atributo src, por exemplo:

```
img.setAttribute('src','caminho')
```

Answer (score 3):

Para atributos reconhecidos pela tag algo como exemplos:

- `Element.src` para tags `<img>`, `<video>`, `<audio>`, `<iframe>`
- `Element.href` para tags `<a>`, `<link>`

reconhecerá como atributo, mas em um elemento diferente cujo o atributo `src` ou `href` não forem próprios no navegador especifico, ou em CustomElements (se não for implementado de forma correta) setar `.src` ou `.href` (ou outro que não seja valido, o que mesmo seguindo as **normas w3** pode variar em certos navegadores) serão setados como **propriedade** e não como atributo, por exemplo:

```js
var teste = document.getElementById('teste');

teste.src = 'https://stackoverflow.blog/wp-content/themes/stackoverflow-oct-19/assets/svg/dist/logo.svg';

console.log('getAttribute:', teste.getAttribute('src'));
```

```html
<p id="teste">elemento p</p>
```

Veja que `getAttribute('src')` retornou `null`

Agora veja quando o atributo é existente/valido para um elemento especifico:

```js
var teste = document.getElementById('teste');

teste.src = 'https://stackoverflow.blog/wp-content/themes/stackoverflow-oct-19/assets/svg/dist/logo.svg';

console.log('getAttribute:', teste.getAttribute('src'));
```

```html
<img src="" id="teste">elemento p</p>
```

Veja que `getAttribute('src')` retornou o endereço da imagem.

Ou seja, para setar atributos customizados ou atributos não padrão o caminho é `setAttribute()`, mas se o atributo for "valido" no elemento pode usar o que chamaremos de atalhos, como `.src` e `.href`.

Por exemplo, alterar a propriedade de um estilo inline CSS com `setAttribute` pode ser complicado, mas com a propriedade style facilita bastante, em um elemento:

```
 <div style="background: #000; color: #fff; font-family: Arial;">
```

E no CSS fizer isto para alterar a cor para laranja:

```
 Element.style.color = "#fc0";
```

Será muito mais simples que usar `setAttribute('style', ...)`

---

### Um pouco de história sobre o Internet Explorer

Sei que é um browser que ninguém mais usa, pelo menos não versões mais antigas que o IE10, a não ser que seja limitado a alguma situação, mas quero falar sobre o comportamento que o IE tinha, propriedades e atributos no IE6, 7 e 8 também se comportavam de forma igual, quero dizer, ao setar uma **propriedade** para um elemento ele se tornava um atributo, mesmo que não fosse uma propriedade valida ali

Veja o teste em emulação do IE8:

> [image: internet explorer 8 ou inferior tratava propriedades como atributos]

O código usado:

```
<div id="teste">DIV de teste</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var teste = document.getElementById('teste');
teste.src = "https://stackoverflow.blog/wp-content/themes/stackoverflow-oct-19/assets/svg/dist/logo.svg";
</script>
```

Já no IE9+ o comportamento foi "corrigido":

> [image: IE9+ o comportamento das propriedades foi corrigido]

Comment: Então no caso eu posso dar um setAttribute no elemento e criar o atributo que eu quiser?

Comment: @IOOISISTEMAS exatamente, você pode criar atributos não padrões para o elemento especifico, mas se souber que o atributo é valido para o elemento "X", então pode usar o atalho "como propriedade" que facilitará a digitar, pois irá digitar menos :)

Comment: E a performance de um e de outro?

Comment: @hugocsl depende e depende, tem quem vá afirmar que propriedade para atributos conhecidos será mais rapido, e é provavel que será mesmo, fiz muitos testes de benchmark, tendo criado meu proprio jQuery com seletor proprio e uma série de funcionalidade e por isto posso lhe afirmar, cada motor de navegador tem um comportamento diferente mas tendo o resultado final igual, no entanto velocidade é algo que sempre varia e poderia até falar disto na resposta, mas não foi bem o que o autor perguntou [...]

Comment: @hugocsl  [...]  creio que o melhor caminho para quem for usar é notar que propeidades validas como atributos é mais fácil de digitar e desenvolver, principalmente se tratando da propriedade global `style` que é suportada por qualquer elemento, ela com certeza é mais simples de usar do que usar setAttribute e isso por si só é o suficiente para avaliar qual a mais pratica de usar.